# java: words extract the capital letter out

Tags: java, regex

how to extract the capital letter out of words using java?

```
example:
enter your words:Hello I Am Heyman
output:HIAH
```

thank

Comment: What about showing us your attempt first?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can try replaceAll

```
String text2 = text.replaceAll("[^A-Z]", "");
```

As @Vic comments, to include all English/Non-English Capital letters.

```
String text2 = text.replaceAll("[^\p{Lu}]", "");
```

Comment: OP should try on his own first.

Comment: Good, but I'd use String text2 = text.replaceAll("[^\p{Lu}]", ""); to ensure that it works for none-English Unicode letters as well.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the solution with a for loop on the String :

```
    String myString = "Hello I Am Heyman";
    String outPutString = "";
    for(int i = 0; i < myString.length(); i++) {
        char c = myString.charAt(i);
        if (Character.isUpperCase(c))
        {
            // it is Capital Letter
            outPutString += c;
        }
    }
    System.out.println(outPutString);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[A-Z]");
Matcher m = p.matcher(textToLookInto);
String outString="";
while(m.find()){
 outString+=m.group();
}
System.out.println(outString);
```

Since you had tagged as regex, so thought to add a regex only solution.

Comment: outString have to be a StringBuilder (faster when textToLookInto come bigger)